# How to Backup over LAN

Tags: 12.04, networking, lan

In 12.04 LTS I would like to get grsync to back up to another Ubuntu PC's hard drive. In Nautilus file manager I can connect to the other PCs OK. How do I address another PC's hard drive in Grsync or other backup package?

Answer (score 1):

In the basic options tab you need to put the address of the remote location:

[image]

A typical example that you can put there is...

```
{username}@{hostname}:/{dir}/{dir}/{dir}
```

where {username} is the name of the user on {host} (ipadres or hostname) and {dir/} the location.

---

[Image found here and it has a very nice how to om the page where I found the image](https://www.sit.auckland.ac.nz/Rsync_and_Grsync_Backups_for_Linux).